# Change HTML using attr jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to update HTML, using attribute of that element. For example :

```
  if($("a.edd-fes-action.edit-product-fes").attr("title")=="Edit"){
      SomeThingHERE.html("Editer");
    }
```

So that in this case, if some element have title attribute "Edit", i want to changes its inner html to some thing else.

Comment: Did your tryied using self selector `$(this)` ?

Comment: No this doesn't works. Here i think $(this) will be current whole DOM.

Comment: Just use the attribute selector `$('a.edd-fes-action.edit-product-fes[title="Edit"]').html('html here');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get elements with `title="Edit"`:

`$('a.edd-fes-action.edit-product-fes[title="Edit"]').html('html here');`